# Rewrite Rule in web.config in webapp hosted on Azure

Tags: php, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to redirect a request https://www.mywebsite.com/product/Apple/Green (not a real link) to https://www.mywebsite.com/product.php?prod=Apple&type=green (not a real link)

I added the following rule in web.config file but it didn't seem to work

```
 <rule name="rwrite">
 <match url="^product/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url=“product.php?prod={R:1}&amp;type={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" /></rule>
```

I tested this code in URL Writer and it gave me the correct output. But if I upload this config file, it loads the product.php file but is not able to load the other JS files & css files included in html section.

Comment: Could you use Chrome DevTools to trace the network activity for links of these JS files & CSS files and share the HTTP response status with us?

Comment: That was really good pointer. The URL for the css and js files are https://www.mywebsite.com/product/apple/<path to CSS or js file>.  Do you know why it is appending the product/apple to the path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a URL rewrite issue. My guess is that you are using the relative path to load JS files & CSS files in HTML section. Maybe something looks like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
```

This would have relation to the URL in the browser's address bar. To prevent this from happening, you'd need to add `/` (which would relative to the root folder of the domain) to begin of file path:

```
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

or use full path with these static files:

```
<script src="http://mywebsite.com/index.js"></script>
```